# how to append multiple values to a list + jQuery

Tags: jquery

Following shows how to manually set each href to the image path and set the class.

```
$.fancybox([{
                            'href'  : '/image/1.jpg',
                            'class' : 'iframe'
                        },
                        {
                            'href'  : '/image/2.jpg',
                            'class' : 'iframe'
                        },
                        {
                            'href'  : '/image?blob_key={{ path }}',
                            'class' : 'iframe'
                        }
                    ], {
                        'padding'           : 0,
```

If I have a loop, how to append the value of those "href" and "class" that are enclosed with curly bracket as shown above to a list in jQuery?

**EDIT**

```
{% for photo in photos %}
// how to add this  "/image?blob_key={{ photo.photo_blobstore_key }} to the $.fancybox ?

{% endfor %}
```

Question Closed:

Solved with:

```
 var options = [];
            {% for photo in photos %}
                options.push({
                    'href'  : 'image?blob_key={{ photo.photo_blobstore_key }}',
                    'class' : 'iframe'
                });
```

Sorry. I wasn't familiar with jQuery and thus asked this simple question. Question Closed as it has been resolved.

Comment: Do you already have the loop when the page loads, or are you adding elements dynamically to your page?

Comment: Please post your solution as an ***answer***, and then, when you can, accept that answer. Otherwise the system considers the question unanswered (or, at least, 'unsolved').

Comment: Thanks David for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var options = [];
   {% for photo in photos %}
      options.push({
          'href'  : 'image?blob_key={{ photo.photo_blobstore_key }}',
          'class' : 'iframe'
      });
   {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to add multiple images inside some container div... Correct?

```
$.each(photos, function(i,e){
    $("#fancybox").append($("<img src='"+ e.href +"' class='"+ e.class +"'/>"));
 });
```